# MSP430F2418: Unable to set P2.3 pin to high

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, gpio, texas-instruments

I am using MSO430F2418 for my project.  I am sending  Hello world message to Bluetooth module via UART pins. Also I need to set pin P2.3 to high to reset the Bluetooth. Unfortunately Im unable to set that perticuler pin to high. When I check the voltage at Reset pin  of Bluetooth it is low.

You can see below two lines in my code. I have used these statements to set the P2.3.

```
P2DIR|=0x08;
P2OUT|=0x08;
```

I have attached an image. There you can see the hardware. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM0MA.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <msp430.h>               


const char string[] = { "Hello World\r\n" };
unsigned int i;

int main(void){
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT

  if (CALBC1_1MHZ==0xFF)                    // If calibration constant erased
  {
    while(1);                               // do not load, trap CPU!!
  }

  DCOCTL = 0;                               // Select lowest DCOx and MODx settings
  BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;                    // Set DCO
  DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;
   P2DIR|=0x08;
   P2OUT|=0x08;
  P3SEL = 0x30;                             // P3.4,5 = USCI_A0 TXD/RXD
  UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_3;                     // SMCLK
  UCA0BR0 = 8;                              // 1MHz 115200
  UCA0BR1 = 0;                              // 1MHz 115200
  UCA0MCTL = UCBRS2 + UCBRS1;               // Modulation UCBRSx = 5
  UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                     // **Initialize USCI state machine**
 // IE2 |= UCA0RXIE;                          // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt
  IE2 |= UCA0TXIE;
  __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);       // Enter LPM0, interrupts enabled
}

#pragma vector=USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI0TX_ISR(void)

{
        UCA0TXBUF = string[i++]; // TX next character
       if (i == sizeof string - 1){ // TX over?
        IE2 &= ~UCA0TXIE; // Disable USCI_A0 TX interrupt
       _delay_cycles(1000000);
        i = 0;
        IE2 |= UCA0TXIE; // Enable USCI_A0 TX interrupt
       }
 }
```

Comment: So your question is if `P2DIR|=0x08; P2OUT|=0x08;` is correct/sufficient to set pin P2.3? Did you measure the voltage directly at the GPIO pin? What hardware do you have between the GPIO pin and the Bluetooth module? Please [edit] your question and add all relevant information there.

Comment: Are you sure your program jumps over the `while(1);`? You can move the instructions for P23 up to the beginning of `main()`.